# Using custom XGBoost model in Flutter app

Tags: machine-learning, flutter, dart, xgboost

Is there a way to use custom XGBoost ML model in Flutter app? Not training, just interface.

Googling seems to show that I should be looking into doing in natively using Swift and Java, is it so?

Answer (score 0):

In short: there is no way. We ended up hooking our model with native platforms and  establishing back-and-forth communication with Flutter via `MethodChannel`.

At the end we ditched the idea of having ML model on board at all because our app size tripled.